# ¿Por qué al ejecutar el programa me suma el doble de filas que deberían tener?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int filas,columnas,matriz[100][100];
    cout<<"por favor introdusca la cantidad de filas : ";cin>>filas;
    cout<<"por favor introdusca la cantidad de columnas : ";cin>>columnas;

    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
              srand(time(NULL));
              matriz[i][j]=1+rand()%(100+1-1);
        }
    }
    cout<<"la matriz quedo de esta forma"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
            cout<< matriz[i][j];                   
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Primero, deberías editar tu pregunta, para que el código quede ordenado y entendible. Segundo, ¿a que te refieres con que suma el doble de filas que debería tener?

Answer (score 5):

Tienes una serie de problemas de estilo en tu código que hacen difícil seguir el problema que planteas.

#### Problemas

---

```
int filas,columnas,matriz[100][100];
```

No has dado valor inicial a ninguna variable; esto no es estrictamente necesario pero además de ser considerado una buena práctica puede ayudarte a detectar errores.

---

```
matriz[100][100];
```

Estás usando una matriz de dimensiones determinadas en [tiempo de compilación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_de_compilaci%C3%B3n) pero después solicitas las dimensiones en [tiempo de ejecución](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_de_ejecuci%C3%B3n) esto es un problema porque...

- Malgastas recursos al solicitar más memoria de la realmente requerida cuando el usuario introduce dimensiones menores a 100.
- Causas [desbordamientos de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer) cuando el usuario introduce alguna dimensión mayor a 100, o ambas.

---

```
for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
          srand(time(NULL));
          matriz[i][j]=1+rand()%(100+1-1);
    }
}
```

Estableces la semilla aleatoria a cada vuelta del bucle, dado que la estableces a el valor del tiempo actual (`time(NULL)`) si el bucle es rápido estarás asignando la misma semilla a cada vuelta; reasignar la misma semilla provoca que la secuencia de números pseudo-aleatorios se reinicie con lo que obtendrás el mismo valor contínuamente.

---

```
(100+1-1)
```

Debería ser evidente que cien más uno menos uno es cien.

---

#### Soluciones

---

Da un valor inicial a tus variables:

```
int filas = 0, columnas = 0;
```

---

Utiliza un contenedor para la matriz, [`std::vector`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) ofrece memoria anexa:

```
std::vector<int> matriz(filas * columnas, 0);
```

---

Establece la semilla fuera del bucle:

```
srand(time(NULL));

for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
          matriz[(i * filas) + j]=1+(rand()%100);
    }
}
```

---

Tras las correcciones, [[no veo qué problema tiene tu código]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/XDx5dcgMVtaxsvyy) ¿Podrías ser más específico?

Por cierto, en los bucles `for` [usa pre-increment siempre que te sea posible](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/).